# Understanding the Networkx find_cliques() function

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, clique, clique-problem

I am currently trying to make an algorithm for finding cliques in a graph, and luckily I found the documentation from Networkx for a function that does just that. Unfortunately, the variable names are a little terse and I'm having trouble understanding what each part of the code does.

Here is the code for find_cliques:

```
def find_cliques(G):
    if len(G) == 0:
        return

    adj = {u: {v for v in G[u] if v != u} for u in G}
    Q = [None]

    subg = set(G)
    cand = set(G)
    u = max(subg, key=lambda u: len(cand & adj[u]))
    ext_u = cand - adj[u]
    stack = []

    try:
        while True:
            if ext_u:
                q = ext_u.pop()
                cand.remove(q)
                Q[-1] = q
                adj_q = adj[q]
                subg_q = subg & adj_q
                if not subg_q:
                    yield Q[:]
                else:
                    cand_q = cand & adj_q
                    if cand_q:
                        stack.append((subg, cand, ext_u))
                        Q.append(None)
                        subg = subg_q
                        cand = cand_q
                        u = max(subg, key=lambda u: len(cand & adj[u]))
                        ext_u = cand - adj[u]
            else:
                Q.pop()
                subg, cand, ext_u = stack.pop()
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

It works just fie, but I just want to understand what is happening here, and I can't seem to find any resources online explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html) of the `find_cliques` method lists three references for this algorithm. You may want to look at them or you take a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Listing_all_maximal_cliques).

Some variables:

`adj`= dictionary storing for each node the neighbours as a set

`u`= the node with the highest number of neighbours, which do not belong to other clique.

`ext_u` = all neighbours of u, which are not member of another clique

Comment: Any idea what cand and Q are?

Comment: If I am not wrong, Q are the nodes of the current clique